How to find an item that has both of another item
I have a table that looks like this



PROV_NBR
CARRIER




P1007794303
KD


P1006831258
CE


P1006831258
KD


P1001141713
KD


P1001141713
CE


117185
KD



I want to find all the PROV_NBR that have both KD and CE Carriers
So the result should just be:



PROV_NBR
CARRIER




P1006831258
CE


P1006831258
KD


P1001141713
KD


P1001141713
CE



I tried
SELECT * 
FROM PRovider 
WHERE CARRIER IN ('KD', 'CE')

but that just returns everything since all the PROV_NBRs have either a KD or CE value for CARRIER.

This also can be achieved by grouping the results by PROV_NBR and then filtering those groups where the count of distinct CARRIER is 2 (i.e., both KD and CE exist).
SELECT PROV_NBR
FROM Provider
WHERE CARRIER IN ('KD', 'CE')
GROUP BY PROV_NBR
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARRIER) = 2

it can be a subquery if you want to show PROV_NBR twice, smth like this
SELECT P.PROV_NBR, P.CARRIER
FROM Provider P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PROV_NBR
    FROM Provider
    WHERE CARRIER IN ('KD', 'CE')
    GROUP BY PROV_NBR
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARRIER) = 2
) AS SubQuery
ON P.PROV_NBR = SubQuery.PROV_NBR
WHERE P.CARRIER IN ('KD', 'CE')


The bottom "WHERE P.CARRIER IN ('KD', 'CE')" is not required

@BartMcEndree why? it is needed to ensure that only the rows with CARRIER as KD or CE are selected. This is because there might be other CARRIER values for the PROV_NBR selected from the subquery, but we are only interested in the rows with KD and CE.

Thanks. I guess we need more records in the example to make that obvious.

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARRIER) = 2 might be faster if you do HAVING MIN(CARRIER) <> MAX(CARRIER) which works only in the specific case of wanting distinct count > 1.

CREATE TABLE PRovider 
(
    PROV_NBR    VARCHAR(512),
    CARRIER VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO PRovider (PROV_NBR, CARRIER) VALUES
    ('P1007794303', 'KD'),
    ('P1006831258', 'CE'),
    ('P1006831258', 'KD'),
    ('P1001141713', 'KD'),
    ('P1001141713', 'CE'),
    ('117185', 'KD');

SELECT P1.* 
FROM PRovider p1
INNER JOIN Provider P2 on P1.PROV_NBR=P2.PROV_NBR AND P2.CARRIER='KD'
INNER JOIN Provider P3 on P1.PROV_NBR=P3.PROV_NBR AND P3.CARRIER='CE'

fiddle



PROV_NBR
CARRIER




P1006831258
CE


P1006831258
KD


P1001141713
KD


P1001141713
CE




This will work, but GROUP BY solution is faster.

Very slow, not necessary and not recommended to select from the same table three times. Simple aggregation is much faster.

@Jonas Metzler I'd like to see an answer with the EXISTS solution please.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78306532/18794826 You can also use IN or EXISTS instead of JOIN, it's anyway far better.

@Jonas Metzler Yes, I have seen the solution by Roman Marusyk. I thought you might have a 3rd solution that is significantly different.
